How to remove a hollow plastic ‘dowel’ stuck in a hole
Y’all, the roller on the top roller of my bifold door broke off. It cracked somehow so there was just the little metal post at the top. As you may know, these posts typically have a plastic base, as did this one. When I tried to pull it out, the metal post became disconnected from the plastic base, which is now stuck in the hole at the top of the door!
I have no idea how to get this thing out so I can put in a new roller. Is there a way to melt down the plastic without also harming the presswood of the door?

Is there enough left for you to get a pair of vise grips on?

Sometimes you can get a thin screwdriver between the wood and plastic and make the plastic collapse.  Then it can them be pulled out with needle nose pliers.
If that doesn't work, drill the hole to restore it to the original size.
Do not try to burn the plastic. You will melt it in the hole and possibly start a fire. At the least ruin the door.

Screwdriver didn’t work but fortunately, I had purchased some larger drill bits. Ended up using a 15/16 in the hole. What I hadn’t anticipated is flecks of plastic flying out as I drilled. Glad I had my sunglasses nearby!

Often a screw screwed into the plastic can give enough purchase to pull it out. If not, the plastic can be drilled out carefully.
